# How to get the current day in Java using LocalDateTime in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the current local day using:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
DayOfWeek  CurrentDay = DayOfWeek.of(now.getDayOfMonth());
```

For me it's Monday but I get Thursday. Why and how can I resolve this?

Comment: `now.getDayOfWeek()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`LocalDateTime.getDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfMonth--) will give you the actual day in the month (beetween 1 - 31)

You are trying to convert that value into the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum using [`DayOfWeek.of(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#of-int-) method accept a value between 1 to 7

> The int value follows the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)

Simply use [`LocalDateTime.getDayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfWeek--) that return the enum directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can just call `now.getDayOfWeek()` directly to get the current local day instead of wrapping it in `DayOfWeek.of`

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); 
DayOfWeek dow = now.getDayOfWeek();
```